# How to wait for an axios call to complete

Tags: javascript, ajax, vue.js, axios

In a vuejs application, I'm trying to initialise an object from data from an ajax call:

```
let settings = {}
api.readConfig().then((config) => {
  settings = {
    userStore: new Oidc.WebStorageStateStore(),
    authority: config.data.urls.auth,
    client_id: config.data.clientid,
    redirect_uri: `${window.location.protocol}//${window.location.hostname}${window.location.port ? `:${window.location.port}` : ''}${process.env.ROUTER_BASE}static/callback.html`,
    response_type: 'id_token token',
    post_logout_redirect_uri: config.data.urls.auth,
  }
})

const authMgr = new Oidc.UserManager(settings)
export default authMgr
```

the object is exported by the call returns, making all the settings null.

How do I wait on the call before exporting my const?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't hold up `export`, but what you can do is something like this, which is call `promise` chain. Here you can transfer the responsibility of resolving the promise to `callee` module.

```
export default api.readConfig().then((config) => {
  return {
    userStore: new Oidc.WebStorageStateStore(),
    authority: config.data.urls.auth,
    client_id: config.data.clientid,
    redirect_uri: `${window.location.protocol}//${window.location.hostname}${window.location.port ? `:${window.location.port}` : ''}${process.env.ROUTER_BASE}static/callback.html`,
    response_type: 'id_token token',
    post_logout_redirect_uri: config.data.urls.auth,
  }
}).then((settings) => {
  return new Oidc.UserManager(settings);
})
```

Then on your `callee` module you can do something like this.

```
var config = require('./config');
config().then((userManager) => {
   ...
})
```